# Assertion failure in sqlite3 using XCode, binding problem?

Tags: xcode, sqlite

```
    -(void)updatepw{

databaseName=@"bestfb.sqlite";

NSArray *documnetPath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documnetDir =[documnetPath objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath=[documnetDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

NSString *update = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"update staff set pword = %@ where staffID=1;", todb];


sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

    const char *sql= (char *) update;
    NSLog(@"new sql :%@", sql);

    NSLog(@"values: %@", newpw.text);



    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) ==SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"prepare failed");
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    else {

        sqlite3_bind_text(selectstmt, 1, [todb UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        NSLog(@"binding done");

    }

    int success1 = sqlite3_step(selectstmt);        
    if (success1 != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to save priority with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);

}   
sqlite3_close(database);

    }
```

Hi all, I've been working on solving the error for hours. 
I could not get the database to update, it would just crash whenever I tries to update.

Anyone who can help is the most welcome!

Please be gentle, as I am only a newbie to XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the single quotes in the below sentence before and after %@

replace with this.

```
NSString *update = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"update staff set pword = '%@' where staffID=1;", todb];
```

Comment: I've done that, and the binding went successfully. However, my application still crashes. Any idea? :(

Comment: My apology, binding is not successful. The statement failed to prepare.

Comment: After replacing the above statement clean all targets and remove the app.And reinstall it.

Comment: I've found the solution for it. There was no problem with the codes, except for 

       NSLog(@"new sql :%@", sql);

The problem lies with the fact that I should not attempt to log a char. :) 

Removed that line and the application and update went smoothly.